# help me resolve this query to insert entries in tables

Tags: mysql

I am working backwards with a query.  I have a select query that fetches some rows...but now I am working backwards and want to insert entries in concerned tables to that the select query brings back the stuff I inserted.

Select Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.catalogID, a.topicID, a.topicShortName
FROM catalog_lu_topics a
LEFT JOIN catalog b ON a.catalogID = b.catalogID
LEFT JOIN catalog_topics d ON ( a.topicID = d.topicID
AND d.topicID != 'top295' )
LEFT JOIN catalog_topics e ON ( (
d.catalogID = e.catalogID
)
AND (
e.topicID != d.topicID
) )
LEFT JOIN catalog_lu_topics f ON f.topicID = e.topicID
WHERE a.displayStatus != 'hide'
AND f.parentID = 'top305'
```

I've inserted entries in the following tables:

```
catalog
catalog_lu_topics (made sure that parentID = 'top305')
catalog_topics (made sure topicid is not top295)
catalog_topics (additional entry, with different topicID)
```

After the insert statements if I run the above query again, i do not see the new entries.  But If I remove the following entries from the above select query then I see the new entries:

```
AND (
    e.topicID != d.topicID
    )
```

I cant wrap my head around this and need some advice.

EDIT: result of select a.* e.topicid, d.topicid (after adding new entries). Note new entries do not show up in this resultset

```
top335      114     Victorian Grace     top301      5   gvl107      Desc    display     2007-03-26 12:38:46     top318      top335
top329  34  Revived Georgian    top301  2   gvl107  Desc    display     2007-03-26 12:38:46     top318  top329
top338  117     DC Townhouse    top301  4   gvl107  Desc    display     2007-03-26 12:38:47     top318  top338
top329  34  Revived Georgian    top301  2   gvl107  Desc    display     2007-03-26 12:38:46     top316  top329
top336  115     Bespoke in Bethesda     top301  6   gvl107  Desc    display     2007-03-26 12:38:46     top316  top336
```

Comment: Can you post the resultset of `select a.*, e.topicId, d.topicId...` before and after that condition is removed?

Comment: with the AND (e.topicID != d.topicID) condition or w/out it?

Comment: I'd like to see both, though I'm concerend to see no `null`s with a bunch of `left join`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what's happening.

When you have that condition in there, you're getting `null`s in your query for all of `e`, which is subsequently used to pull back `f`, which you then filter on. Ergo, you're doing an `inner join` but going about it in a roundabout way.

The update:

So, the entries added contained:

```
a.catalogid = 297
a.topicid = top398

d.catalogid = 298
d.topicid = top398

e.catalogid = 299
e.topicid = top400
```

So, when `a` joins to `d`, it goes via the `topicid`, and lo and behold, finds something. Then `d` takes that `catalogid` (`298`), and matches it up to `e`. Except, `e` doesn't find anything, so returns `null`. Then `f` tries to join with `e.topicid`. Sadly, `e.topicid` is `null`, but there's an `f.parentid` value in the `where` clause. Therefore, this row gets filtered out.

Comment: I just recently added: 1) catalogID = '297' to catalog table. 2) topicID = 'top398' into catalog_lu_topics. 3) topicID = 'top399' into catalog_lu_topics again. 4) catalogid = '298' into catalog_topics 5) catalogid = '299' into catalog_topics again.

Comment: That returns just one topic (398), and so fails that `e.topicid != d.topicid` condition, making its `f.parentid null`, making it go away in the query.

Comment: Ah, see, `e` and `d` are matching on the `d.catalogid`, and the only `d.catalogid` with a `topicid` of `top398`, the `a.topicid`, is `298`. Therefore, since there's only one `topic` row that meets these criteria, it gets filtered out with the `e.topicid != d.topicid`.

Comment: so where do you think i need to add more so that and e.topicID != d.topicID condition passes and does not return nulls

Comment: Add a record in `catalog_topics` that is `catalogid: 298` and `topicid: top399`. That should do it!

Comment: Or do `update catalog_topics set catalogid = 298 where topicid = 'top400'`

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!